# Proxmox Wget not working stuck on HTTP request sent, awaiting response... / after connection success

Tags: linux, wget, proxmox

if i try to wget a file on proxmox like downloading a template or inside the host shell, i keep getting HTTP request sent, awaiting response... ,  for example trying to download the template [text](http://download.proxmox.com/images/system/ubuntu-23.10-standard_23.10-1_amd64.tar.zst) for ubuntu 23.10 i get this:
[image]

But if i try to do inside a VM i can download it without any problem at all, idk what is wrong with my proxmox.

If i try with curl -v i get:
[image]

Already tried changing dns server but i don't think it's a DNS problem cuz i can resolve the domain name.

Comment: So i discover what my problem is, if i have ipv6 enabled i can't get the proxmox to download files via ipv6, the strange thing is that all my vms with ipv6 work, i have native ipv6 connection, i disabled my ipv6 on my host machine while still enabled on my vms for the time being, if anybody knows how i can fix this, please help.

Comment: If you happen to have the same problem, a workaround is to set inet4_only = on to /etc/wgetrc config file and this option is set globally to all wget commands.